# Understanding upsert with $push

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a region collection:

```
var RegionSchema = new Mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String},
  registrations: [{type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'registrations'}],
  ...
});
```

A registration collection:

```
var RegistrationSchema = Mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type: String},
  ...
});
```

In my controller I instantiate a registration then save it to my region with the `upsert` option set to `true`:

```
var registration = new Registration(req.body.registration);
...
Region
  .update(
    { _id: user.region},
    { $push: {registrations: registration},
    { upsert: true }
  )
  .exec();
```

What I find is that an `ObjectId("...")` does, in fact, get pushed onto the registrations property of the region, e.g.:

```
{
  name: "Northwest",
  registrations: [ObjectId("57d038a1466345d52920b194")]
}
```

but there is no matching document with that `_id` in the registrations collection. So my question: what am I not understanding about the nature of the `upsert` flag; does it not suggest that calling `save` on the registration is unnecessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `upsert` flag only applies to the collection you're operating on; in this case, the `Region` collection. So, when calling `Region.update`, it will create an object with `_id` of `user.region` if an object with that ID doesn't exist.

Mongo doesn't enforce strict ID references, so it will let you push an ID onto `registrations` so long as the ID is valid.

You'll need to save the `Registration` object first:

```
var registration = new Registration(req.body.registration);

registration.save(function() {
  Region.update(
    { _id: user.region },
    { $push: { registrations: registration } },
    { upsert: true }
  ).exec();
});
```

Comment: Is not so important, but your parentheses are not balanced, the command is missing one closed curly bracket